# how to export react js screenshot to pptx format?

Tags: reactjs, powerpoint

hey guys i want to take screenshot of our react js page and then save it in pptx format. i did for pdf and its working fine . google results are not enough for me to resolve this pptx issue .
as u can see in below pictures my pdf method . this is same how via id i want to do with pptx ..thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: i check the documentation of pptxgenjs and this is code link of thier demo but this is not complete file . https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/demo/react/index.html